# Is it possible to add an item to a site level list in Sharepoint 2010 with REST API?

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, post, sharepoint-2010

I have a site which I am currently able to retrieve/add/delete list items:

```
http://portal/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Announcements
```

I can retrieve data from the following url:

```
http://portal/site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/HQAnnouncements
```

But when I try to POST data to that list, I get the following error:

```
Error processing request stream. The request should be a valid top-level resource object.
```

When I gave improper field data to the first URL, I received an error mentioning the Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.AnnouncementsItem item type.  Is it possible that this object model is somehow unaware of my custom site level Announcements item list?

I would really like to be able to write data to that site level list. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

This was a whole lot easier than I thought it may be.

The answer is to pay attention to the field names.

I had a field "Discipline" on the "Add Announcement" form.  Since it was a drop down, the data service showed the field name as "DisciplineValue".

Lesson: PAY ATTENTION TO THE DATA AS IT ARRIVES TO YOU BEFORE TRYING TO WRITE NEW ITEMS.

Also, bad error code perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Browse to your REST url:

in your example:  http://portal/site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/HQAnnouncements(2)

Choose some **valid id**. Copy the columns directly from the result set. This insures you have the correct names AND capitalization.